# Pythin kivy how to turn off texture antialiasing

Tags: python, kivy, rendering, textures, antialiasing

I have a texture with an average size of 120 by 80 that changes every frame. It is created from an array of numbers using

```
    def draw(self, t):
        self.buf = t
        self.texture_array = array('B', self.buf)
        self.size = Window.size
        self.padding_x = Window.size[0] * 0.25
        self.padding_y = Window.size[1] * 0.25
        self.pix_size_x = Window.size[0] * 0.75
        self.pix_size_y = Window.size[1] * 0.75
        self.tex.blit_buffer(self.texture_array, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        with self.canvas:
            Rectangle(texture = self.tex, pos = (self.padding_x, self.padding_y), size = (self.pix_size_x, self.pix_size_y))
```

It should look like pixel art, but the texture smoothing spoils the whole picture. Is it possible to somehow disable anti-aliasing or do another way to render the array?

Answer (score 0):

The texture has `mag_filter` and `min_filter` properties, set these both to `"nearest"`.